# Three level deep map with async/await

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await

I need to fetch data from three table (using nodejs & mysql), posts, comments & replies and below is the approach I tried but not getting expected result. Can anyone please look into my code.

```js
try {
  feeds = await db.getPosts('', offset = 0, limit = 3);
  await Promise.all(
    feeds.map(async(feed, i) => {
      let cmts = await cmnt.getCommentsByPostId(feed.id);

      feeds[i].comments = JSON.stringify(cmts);

      await Promise.all(
        feeds[i].comments = cmts.map(async(cmt, j) => {
          cmts[j].replies = await cmnt.getRepliesByCommentId(cmt.id);
        })
      )
    })
  )

} catch (err) {
  console.log(err)
}
```

I need everything(posts, comments & their replies) in `feeds` variable so that I can iterate using multiple (loop inside loop) in template.I also tried to call `getCommentsByPostId()` in template inside foreach loop but that didn't work.

Comment: `I tried but not getting expected result` and `but that didn't work` are not really helpful descriptions of your problem.

Comment: when iterating `feeds` in template (ejs), getting `comments: [ Promise { undefined } ] }`

Comment: How can we know whether that is what you expect, or not what you expect? A promise is a handy value, but are you saying you are not happy with it?

Comment: The methods of `Array` do not work with `async` functions. All you can do is to let the callbacks return promises then await all of them after `feeds.map()`.

Comment: Why do you stringify the comments? How will you ever get the replies then since the `cmts` variable is no longer available after you exit your function?

Comment: @trincot, even  when I am not stringify comments, its not working

Comment: yes, but there is a lot more wrong. Please provide the function definition in which this code is present, and how you call it, and where you print the expected result. Please provide what the input is (a sample) from the database calls you make, and the expected, final output. All this is needed for us to understand the question and to be able to give a useful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your code, let's try to address them:

(1) You're getting comments as `Promise { undefined }` because inside your first mapping function, you're not returning anything (ie `undefined`), so your first `Promise.all` is resolving immediately and not waiting for comments and replies to resolve.

To fix it, you must return your second `Promise.all` to make a promise chain that ends with the `await cmnt.getRepliesByCommentId(cmt.id)` call

(2) Also, you're assigning `feeds[i].comments = cmts.map(async(cmt, j) => {` inside the second `Promise.all`. You shouldn't do that.

(3) And finally, as you're stringifying `cmts` when assigning them to `feeds[i]`, you're losing its reference, so later when you do `cmts[j].replies = ...`, that change won't take effect in `feeds[i].comments`.

```js
try {
  feeds = await db.getPosts('', offset = 0, limit = 3);
  await Promise.all(
    feeds.map(async(feed, i) => {
      let cmts = await cmnt.getCommentsByPostId(feed.id);

      feeds[i].comments = cmts; // (3)

      return Promise.all( // <-------------------- (1)
        cmts.map(async(cmt, j) => { // <---------- (2)
          cmts[j].replies = await cmnt.getRepliesByCommentId(cmt.id);
        })
      )
    })
  )

} catch (err) {
  console.log(err)
}
```

Comment: `[ RowDataPacket {
    firstname: 'Irphan',
    lastname: 'Khan',
    profile_pic: '2_1575024910502.png',
    id: 2,
    user_id: 2,
    createdAt: 2019-11-29T11:06:57.000Z,
    updatedAt: 2019-11-29T11:06:57.000Z,
    comments: [ [Promise], [Promise] ] },
  RowDataPacket {
    firstname: 'Irphan',
    lastname: 'Khan',
    profile_pic: '2_1575024910502.png',
    id: 1,
    user_id: 2,
    createdAt: 2019-11-29T07:03:35.000Z,
    updatedAt: 2019-11-29T07:03:35.000Z,
    comments: [ [Promise] ] } ]
`

Comment: This is the output I am getting. also `replies` key value is missing. Also comments not accessible using for loop

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that you're assigning `feeds[i].comments = cmts.map()` within the second `Promise.all`. You shouldn't do that, because then you're assigning the mapping result (array of promises) again. I'm updating the code

Comment: Thank You so much for the help. Got expected result.

Comment: one quick question: Do you think there can be more efficient way to fetch these type of record combination  (posts, comments& replies) using nodejs  ?

Comment: @Irphan in terms of performance, with the apis I see in your code (getPosts, getCommentsByPostId, getRepliesByCommentId) I can't think of a better way. You could fetch all those things at once from your db with a complex query, but I couldn't say without knowing the software

Comment: I wanted to prepare a single query for all these 3 (posts, their comments & their replies) but couldn't do .I tried sub-query and joins but  nothing was working (using sub-query, its was returning only single record.). To know software, you can consider facebook's post & comment system, I need to implement exactly same in my software.

Comment: You'd be better off posting a new question with the query related issue. Post the queries you have, and how you'd like to combine them, and what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

The first `Promise.all` seem fine, you put a promise array to `Promise.all`, good.
But, at the second block, you does not do that the same with first block.

Promise.all requires a promise array as first parameter. In your code, you put a `void` value to `Promise.all`, because assign operation (`feeds[i].comments =  ...` return "void").

My suggestion to fix on your way,

```
try {
  feeds = await db.getPosts('', offset = 0, limit = 3);
  await Promise.all(
    feeds.map(async (feed, i) => {
      let cmts = await cmnt.getCommentsByPostId(feed.id);

      feeds[i].comments = JSON.stringify(cmts); // ????

      await Promise.all( // here
        cmts.map(async (cmt, j) => { // map returns array, in this case in returns Promise<void>[]
          cmts[j].replies = await cmnt.getRepliesByCommentId(cmt.id);
        })
      ) 
      // get all replies of each comments are done!
      feeds[i].comments = cmts; // comment with replies
    })
  )

  console.log(feeds); // feeds includes comment's replies.

} catch (err) {
  console.log(err)
}
```

Comment: Just a note: without a declaration (`var`, `let`, `const`), an assignment operation in js doesn't return void but the assigned value. The problem here was that given this behavior, it was overwriting `feeds[i].comments` with the array of promises.